# Utilizando Elementos como "Not Exists" e Sub Query no LINQ, LAMBDA EXPRESSION e Nhibernate

Tags: linq, expressões-lambda, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-sql

Bom Dia,
Tenho uma query a ser executada em minha base de dados, porem, aqui em nossos projetos utilizamos o Nhibernate como ferramenta de ORM.
Estou tendo dificuldade em passar esta query SQL para uma sintaxe utilizada com NHibernate.

A query é esta baixo:

`SELECT distinct a.NumContrOper 
  FROM [tb_viw_cdc_par] a
  inner join 
  tb_viw_cdc_ope b
  on a.NumContrOper = b.NumContrOper
  and a.CodCliente = b.CodCliente
   where [TipParc] in (1,3,8,10)
    and not exists (select * from [tb_viw_cdc_par] par where par.[TipParc]  in (2,9) and
    par.NumContrOper = b.NumContrOper
  and par.CodCliente = b.CodCliente);`

Percebam que nela, utilizo uma clausula `not exists` e tambem uma subquery para complementar a minha consulta. Quero a ajuda de vocês para saber como posso montar essa subquery utilizando tbm o termo 'Not Exists' na sixtaxe do NHibernate, Linq ou lambda expression.

Segue uma parte da query que estou conseguindo montar:

```
private IQueryable<string> BuscarParcFut(ParcelaAlfandegaEntidadeFiltro aFiltros)
    {
        IQueryable<OperacaoAlfandegaEntidade> operacaoAlfandega = this.Buscar<OperacaoAlfandegaEntidade>();
        List<int?> tiposNot = new List<int?>();

        tiposNot.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.ParcelaFutura.ComoString()));
        tiposNot.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.ParcelaFuturaConsorcio.ComoString()));


        List<int?> tipos = new List<int?>();
        tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.ParcelaAnterior.ComoString()));
        tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.PagamentoAvulso.ComoString()));
        tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.ParcelaAnteriorConsorcio.ComoString()));
        tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.PagamentoAvulsoConsorcio.ComoString()));

        var query = BuscarBasico(aFiltros)
            .Join(operacaoAlfandega,
                                a => new { Contrato = a.Contrato, CpfCnpj = a.CpfCnpj },
                                b => new { Contrato = b.Contrato, CpfCnpj = b.CpfCnpj },
                                (a, b) =>
                                    new
                                    {
                                        Parcela = a,
                                        Operacao = b,
                                    })
                                    .Where(w => tipos.Contains(w.Parcela.TipoParcela)
                                    )
                                    .Select(a => a.Parcela.Contrato)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    ;




        return query;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria importante se você incluisse sua entidade e seu mapeamento, para que a partir disso seja mais fácil identificar a modelagem e relacionamentos entre essas duas entidades.

Dessa maneira está gerando algum resultado? Você tem o SQL que gerou esse resultado?

Enfim, com as informações que você disponibilizou aqui, minha sugestão é um código mais ou menos assim (adequar apenas aos métodos que você utiliza):

```
List<int?> tipos = new List<int?>();
tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.ParcelaAnterior.ComoString()));
tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.PagamentoAvulso.ComoString()));
tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.ParcelaAnteriorConsorcio.ComoString()));
tipos.Add(int.Parse(TipoParcelaEnumerador.PagamentoAvulsoConsorcio.ComoString()));

IQueryable<Operacao> queryOperacoes = Buscar<Operacao>();

IQueryable<Parcela> queryParcelas = BuscarBasico(aFiltros)
  .Where(w => tipos.Contains(w.Parcela.TipoParcela) && 
              !queryOperacoes.Any(o => o.Contrato == w.Contrato && o.CpfCnpj == w.CpfCnpj));

var resultado = queryParcelas.Select(s => s.Parcela.Contrato).Distinct().ToList();
```

Removi o JOIN do código, pois você não está utilizando ele no Select.
Inclui no WHERE uma verificação Any no IQueryable das Operações, onde basicamente vai fazer o seguinte no final: me traga as parcelas que não tem nenhuma operação dado um contrato e cpf/cnpj. posteriormente é obtido apenas o numero do contrato.